# CSV File ArcMap Geocoding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, csv, latitude-longitude

Newbie here trying to figure out how to work with Excel data in ArcMap. I am currently using ArcMap ArcGIS for Personal Use. Before my online ArcGIS Online subscription ran out I managed to add a layer of Excel real estate data and the coordinates were as I intended. This was due to the address geocoding feature I suppose. After displaying x y data, I would geocode address and it would work fine. However, the online free trial ran out I have not been able to geocode addresses inside of ArcMap. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have tried everything and the data is showing on the map halfway across the world. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your excel sheet. Also how many addresses to you have in total?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  You say you "have tried everything" but haven't told us what you've tried.  Please [edit] your question to include some detail about what you've tried (and how) and also include a sample of your CSV file data so potential answerers have an idea of what you're using and can test for themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a function to upload or add screenshots. I would be happy to provide an example. How do I do this?

Comment: @steven77 [edit] your question and use the Image button from the edit toolbar to add an image.  You could also cut/paste some of the text from your CSV rather than trying to include an image if that's easier.

Comment: Data showing up halfway across the world is likely one of three problems: (1) you have lat and lon switched (very common when moving from one platform to another, shouldn't be an issue within ESRI products); (2) you might need to designate west or south coordinates with a negative sign; or most likely (3) you have a projection mismatch -- say you computed decimal degrees latitude and longitude, but somehow you told ArcMap your layer is UTM (meters) instead.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you are mixing up "Display XY Data" and "Geocoding."  The former is for when you already have coordinates in a spreadsheet, and you wish to plot them on the map.  The latter is for when you have a street address and need ArcMap to go look up the coordinates.  Can you clarify which is your situation?

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. I was away for a bit but this morning I cleaned up the sheet a bit and ran it through Geocodio and exactly 50% of my data is mapped correctly now. I'm not sure why the other 50 is not working correctly as it is formatted the same as thee 50% that is. working. J Kelly, I am was geocoding it at first through ArcMap but now have been using x y data. I will tinker a bit and provide an update soon. Thanks